# Angular4, can't hide content

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

i have component in angular 4 framework that looks like this

```
import { ListService } from '../list/list.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'view',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="row?.id">
    <div>
      <p>{{row.id}}</p>
      <p>{{row.name}}</p>
      <p>{{row.weight}}</p>
      <p>{{row.symbol}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!row">test</div> 
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: ListService) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = parseInt(params['id']);
      if (id) {
        this.row = this.service.getRow(id);
        console.log(this);
      }
    });
  }

  row;

  ngOnInit() { }
  showInfo(){
      console.log(this)
  }
}
```

while first `*ngIf="row?.id"` works just fine, the second behaves strange meaning is always `true`, have i done something wrong?

**EDIT:**

when i tested it it seems that ViewComponent is not updated properly, meaning when i execute `console.log` inside `constructor > after if condition` Viewcomponent have 3 properties `route`, `service` and `row` but when i created function

```
showInfo(){
    console.log(this)
}
```

now `this` -> `ViewComponent` have only 2 properties `route`, and `service`

can this be some problem with scope ?

Comment: When do you expect it to be false?

Comment: i expects it will be false when no one have clicked on any row

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following

```
<div *ngIf="row === undefined">test</div>
```

`*ngIf="!row"` is checking that `row === false`

Comment: `!row` is not equivalent to `row === false`, but to `row == false`

Answer (score 0):

`*ngIf="!row"` checks that row is a falsy value (meaning `row == false`, which in turn can mean, if row is an object, that row is either `null` or `undefined`).

As long as your row is **not null or undefined**, this condition will be true and 'test' will appear.

If you want the opposite check of your first `*ngIf`, just negate it entirely :

```
<div *ngIf="!(row?.id)">test</div>
```

(parenthesis just for clarity)